# PyQT5 'QPoint' object has no attribute 'pos'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i have some problem on pyQT5. In the TextArea section, when I right click a word, I want to open a menu and print the synonyms of the word there. I found a sample menu function but I get the error in the header (PyQT5 'QPoint' object has no attribute 'pos'). What does this stem from? Is there another way I can follow?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton,QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize  
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
                             QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                             QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QMenu)

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen,QCursor

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    fileName=""
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;") 
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(1080, 720))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Simurg") 
        self.choose_file_button()
        self.textareaMain()
        self.textareaSimurg()
        self.selectItem()
        self.chooseSimurgFunciton()
        text=QPlainTextEdit()
        outputText = QTextEdit()

    def chooseSimurgFunciton(self):
        pybutton = QPushButton('Fonksiyonu Uygula', self)
        pybutton.resize(150,32)
        pybutton.move(460, 5)


    def choose_file_button(self):
        pybutton = QPushButton('Dosya Sec', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.chooseFile)
        pybutton.resize(100,32)
        pybutton.move(10, 5)

    def chooseFile(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        self.fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        self.text.setPlainText(open(self.fileName).read())
        if self.fileName:
            print(self.fileName)
        print('Clicked Pyqt button.')

    def textareaMain(self):
        self.text = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.text.insertPlainText("Ana yazı buraya gelecek.\n")
        self.text.move(10,60) #1.para sol sağ 2. para alt-üst
        self.text.resize(525,450)
        #yazıldıkça veriyi çek.
        self.text.textChanged.connect(
            lambda: print(self.text.document().toPlainText()))
        self.text.selectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelectionChanged)
        

    def handleSelectionChanged(self):
        cursor = self.text.textCursor()
        print ("Selection start: %d end: %d" % 
           (cursor.selectionStart(), cursor.selectionEnd()))
        string=str(self.text.document().toPlainText())
        print("\033[1;31m"+string[cursor.selectionStart():cursor.selectionEnd()]+"\033[0m")
        word=string[cursor.selectionStart():cursor.selectionEnd()]
        redColor = QColor(255, 0, 0)
        blue = QColor(0, 0, 255)
        self.outputText.setTextColor(redColor)
        self.outputText.insertPlainText(" "+word)
        self.outputText.setTextBackgroundColor(blue)
        self.outputText.insertPlainText(" selam ")
        self.text.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.text.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showMenu)

    

    def showMenu(self,event):
        contextMenu = QMenu(self)
        newAct = contextMenu.addAction("New")
        openAct = contextMenu.addAction("Open")
        quitAct = contextMenu.addAction("Quit")
        action = contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action == quitAct:
            self.close()

    def textareaSimurg(self):
        self.outputText = QTextEdit(self)
        self.outputText.insertPlainText("Simurg sonucu buraya gelecek. Altı çizili bir şekilde.\n")
        self.outputText.move(545,60) #1.para sol sağ 2. para alt-üst
        self.outputText.resize(525,450)

    def selectItem(self):
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box.setGeometry(150,5,300,30)
        geek_list = ["Lütfen Bir Fonksiyon Seçin","Kelime Türkçe Mi?","Doğru Bilinen Yanlışlar","Özne-Yüklem İlişkisi"]
        self.combo_box.addItems(geek_list)
        self.combo_box.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
    
    def selectionchange(self,i):
        print ("Items in the list are :")
        for count in range(self.combo_box.count()):
            print (self.combo_box.itemText(count))
        print ("Current index",i,"selection changed ",self.combo_box.currentText())
        if(i==2):
            metin=self.text.document().toPlainText()

    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) #def
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`QWidget::customContextMenuRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal passes a `QPoint` as its parameter, so the argument to `showMenu` is also a `QPoint`.

Change the definition of `showMenu` to (untested)...

```
def showMenu(self,pos):
    contextMenu = QMenu(self)
    newAct = contextMenu.addAction("New")
    openAct = contextMenu.addAction("Open")
    quitAct = contextMenu.addAction("Quit")
    action = contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
    if action == quitAct:
        self.close()
```